# Display correct objects/keys from array in string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to display items from an array in my tableView cells, in a string. Currently, I'm using these lines of code:

**.m**

```
id swaptime = self.filteredTotal[0][@"swaptime"];

NSString *test = swaptime;
```

...to grab the value located in *swaptime*, and display it in each of my cells. That said, in all of my cells, this line forces them all to display only the FIRST swaptime value - rather than the list of swaptime values from my array in their corresponding cells. Is this because of the [0] in my line (e.g. only grab the value located at 0)? If so, how should it be written instead so that all values are displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the answer since you have not provided all of your code, but if the code shown above is from the `cellForRowAt` method of the `UITableView` datasource, then this should work:

```
id swaptime = self.filteredTotal[indexPath.row][@"swaptime"];
```

(provided you do not intend on having more than 1 section)